# Cannot use subqueries on a criteria without a projection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

NHibernate.QueryException: 'Cannot use subqueries on a criteria without a projection.'

Base Error:

```
            WorkEntity workEntity = null;
            QueryOver<WorkEntity, WorkEntity> result = QueryOver.Of(() => workEntity);

            Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.Conjunction();
            QueryOver<WorkDetailEntity, WorkDetailEntity> workDetailEntity = QueryOver.Of<WorkDetailEntity>();

            foreach (ISearchSpecsFilter item in searchFilter.SpecsFilter) {

                if (item.MinValue + item.MinValue != 0) {

                    conjunction.Add(Restrictions.Where<WorkDetailEntity>(w => w.Value >= item.MinValue && w.Value <= item.MaxValue));

                }

            }

            result
                .WithSubquery
                .WhereExists(workDetailEntity.Where(conjunction).And(w => w.Work.WorkId == workEntity.WorkId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

Error:

```
result
  .WithSubquery
  .WhereExists(workDetailEntity.Where(conjunction).And(w => w.Work.WorkId == workEntity.WorkId));
```

Correct:

```
result
  .WithSubquery
  .WhereExists(workDetailEntity.Where(conjunction).And(w => w.Work.WorkId == workEntity.WorkId).Select(s => s.Work.WorkId));
```